# Make [google-login] a synonym of [google-signin]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Please help to make the following synonym

[google-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-login) --> [google-signin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-signin)

Both tags refers to the same API and to the same documentation -> https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

## google-login (1,103 questions)

### Excerpt

> Google-login refers to a sign-in API provided by Google.

### Wiki

> Google provides an API to allow developers to integrate a secure and
> quick way in their apps to log their users in using a registration
> system they are already using and trust most. There is full guidance
> available
> [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).
>
> **Top Links**
>
> 1. [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)

## google-signin (3,249 questions)

### Excerpt

> Google Sign-In allows users to sign in to your application with their Google accounts

### Wiki

> By adding [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/), you bring the power of Google to your
> site or application. When a user is signed in, you get an OAuth token
> for making API requests on their behalf, which you can use to better
> understand your user, connect them with their friends, and create a
> richer and more engaging experience.
>
> You can also add the Google+ Sign-In button to your [Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) or
> [iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) app.
>
> Minimal implementations
>
> ---
>
> **Web**
>
> Include the required JS headers
>
> ```
> <head>
>   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp"
> ```
>
> async defer>
>
> Put a placeholder for containing the button
>
> ```
> <body>
>   <!-- ... -->
>   <div id="gConnect">
>     <div id="signin-button"></div>
>   </div>
>   <!-- ... -->
> </body>
> ```
>
> Render the button and handle user sign-in
>
> ```
> function startApp() {
>   gapi.load('auth2', function() {
>     gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {
>       gapi.signin2.render('signin-button', {
>           scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
>           fetch_basic_profile: false });
>       gapi.auth2.init({fetch_basic_profile: false,
>           scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'}).then(
>             function (){
>               console.log('init');
>               auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
>               auth2.isSignedIn.listen( function() {
>                   console.log(auth2.currentUser.get());
>                 });
>               auth2.then(function(resp){
>                   console.log(auth2.currentUser.get());
>                 });
>             });
>     });
>   });
> }
> ```

Comment: Thumbs up for the request, but unfortunately, I don't have the required score to help - reposted in the community chat room, maybe someone with the score will notice and help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. Merged the following tags:

#### 1. [google-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-login) > [google-signin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-signin)

```
updating post history, 1284 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 1100 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 1038 rows affected
destroying 'google-login': [google-login] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 4282
tag remapping of [google-signin] and [google-login] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
61 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
72 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym google-login -> google-signin was approved!
```

#### 2. [googlesigninapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesigninapi) > [google-signin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-signin)

```
updating post history, 219 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 195 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 54 rows affected
destroying 'googlesigninapi': [googlesigninapi] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 4336
tag remapping of [google-signin] and [googlesigninapi] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
10 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
3 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym googlesigninapi -> google-signin was approved!
```

Comment: Thank you very much Samuel and the people supporting this request.